# Segmentation fault in C++ SDL project

Tags: c++, function, segmentation-fault, sdl

Why do I have a segmentation fault in this function, specifically in the line with the DisplayFormat function? I have encountered this problem several times and don't know how to fix it.

```
SDL_Surface* imageBlitingFunctions::loadIMG(std::string filename)
{
    SDL_Surface *img = IMG_Load(filename.c_str());

    SDL_Surface *imgOPT = SDL_DisplayFormat(img);

    SDL_FreeSurface(img);

    return imgOPT;
}
```

Comment: have you checked `img != 0` ?

Comment: No, as you can see I declared the pointer inside the function.

Comment: @TheBlackSword _'No, as you can see I declared the pointer inside the function.'_ And in which way does this hinder you to apply a simple check for the proper result of `IMG_Load()`?

Comment: **Why** do you not check `img != 0`?  Would that not prevent segmentation faults?

Comment: The documentation explicitly tells you that IMG_Load returns 0 if it failed to load the image. SDL_Display also assumes you are providing it a valid pointer. When you don't, it segfaults. It is your responsibility to make sure you have a valid pointer, which is why you to check the return value from IMG_Load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code as follows

```
SDL_Surface* imageBlitingFunctions::loadIMG(std::string filename)
{
    SDL_Surface *img = IMG_Load(filename.c_str());
    if(img == NULL) {
        std::cerr << "ERROR: image load failed: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        return NULL;
    }

    SDL_Surface *imgOPT = SDL_DisplayFormat(img);

    SDL_FreeSurface(img);

    return imgOPT;
}
```

to get over the segmentation fault, and get some information what actually went wrong with `IMG_Load()`.

Also don't forget to check the return value outside your function not being `NULL`, before making use of it.